# I cannot use a datetime parameter inside the execute statement

Tags: date, t-sql, parameters, execute

In this below mentioned query, I am trying to use the paramter@PARAM_D inside the Execute section, but it throws the error:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
> The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the add operator.

What can be going wrong here? I am able to use other varchar parameters but not the date parameters only.

```
DECLARE @C VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @PARAM_D DATE = '2021-07-31'

if 1=1

  set @C = 'SELECT '+@PARAM_D +'as col1_X'

else

  set @C = 'SELECT ''ABC'' as col1_x '

execute(@c)

print @PARAM_D
```

Comment: You need to use [cast or convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) -- and use cast / convert the second time to get it to be a date column instead of varchar in the statement you're creating. Just use `print @c` and try to run your statement so you'll see

Comment: The main issue is that you work with different types of data together and by doing this, you enforce SQL Server to do implicit CONVERT which lead to failure in this case. But again, the issue is not specific place in the query but from the start to end including places that the server succeed with the implicit convert! To be more specific about the error, then the source is from doing this `'SELECT '+@PARAM_D +'as col1_X'` which make no sense. How can you add string to date?!? A date is totally different type. It is like doing: `1km + 1hour` which make no sense!

Comment: You can use CONVERT with specific format style in order to represent a Date as string with specific format

Comment: Why are you using a "dynamic" statement at all here when there's no need for it.

Answer (score 0):

From [+ (Addition)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/add-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments): "Cannot be used with `date`, `time`, `datetime2`, or `datetimeoffset` data types."

If you change the `date` value to a string you can concatenate it with the other strings:

```
set @C = 'select ''' + Cast( @Param_D as VarChar(30) ) + ''' as Col1_X;';
```

To make the actual value returned be a `date` data type you need to `cast` it back:

```
set @C = 'select Cast( ''' + Cast( @Param_D as VarChar(30) ) + ''' as Date ) as Col1_X;';
```

Aside: Although it isn't a problem here, you might want to read up on [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).